# Can a gem used as the material component for the Magic Jar spell also be used for the Imprisonment spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

I want to cast *[Magic Jar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar)* to transfer my soul into a gem, then possess someone, then cast *[Imprisonment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment)* (using the Minimus Containment option) on my now-soulless body to store it safely into the same gem, making it indestructible at the same time.

**Can the gem used as a material component for *Magic Jar* also be used for *Imprisonment*?**

Comment: Related : [Is my soulless catatonic body a creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153951/is-my-soulless-catatonic-body-a-creature)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes it can.

There's nothing in the rules, or either spell, which says that the material component used for one of these spells can't also be used for the other. The gem isn't consumed by either spell, and as long as the gem meets the requirements for both spells in value and size, you should be able to use it for both.

However, note this wording:

> Light can pass through the gemstone normally (allowing the target to see out and other creatures to see in), but **nothing else can pass through**, even by means of teleportation or planar travel.

This implies that your soul cannot travel into and out of the gem while Imprisonment is in effect. So if your soul is still in the gem, you can't possess a creature until Imprisonment ends. Likewise if you have possessed a creature, your soul cannot return to the gem until Imprisonment ends.

Fortunately, Imprisonment allows you to set a condition for ending the spell:

> The condition can be as specific or as elaborate as you choose, but the GM must agree that the condition is reasonable and has a likelihood of coming to pass.

So you could set the condition that Imprisonment ends, for example, when the body you're possessing through Magic Jar dies. Work with your DM to get the condition exactly right for your purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure the last paragraph works. From the _Imprisonment_ description: "The conditions can be based on a creature's name, identity, or deity but otherwise must be based on observable actions or qualities **and not based on intangibles such as level, class, or hit points**" (emphasis mine). So "dies" is valid, but I don't think "drops to zero hit points" is.

Comment: "Falls unconscious" is not really a good substitute for "drops to zero HP", since it will also trigger when you go to bed for the night. "Knocked unconscious" might work, but may not cover things like being put to sleep by magic (no knocking involved).

Comment: Can we bikeshed this in chat, please?