# Is my soulless catatonic body a valid target for the Imprisonment spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

I want to cast *[Magic Jar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar)* to transfer my soul into a gem, then possess someone, then cast *[Imprisonment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment)* on my now-soulless body to store it safely and be able to carry it everywhere with me in case my new body dies.

**Is my soulless catatonic body a valid target for *Imprisonment* ?**

Comment: Related : [Can a Magic Jar gem be used to cast Imprisonment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153950/can-a-magic-jar-gem-be-used-to-cast-imprisonment)

Comment: Note: "Light can pass through the gemstone normally (allowing the target to see out and other creatures to see in), but **nothing else** can pass through, even by means of teleportation or planar travel." I am pretty sure your soul will not be able to go back to your imprisoned body...

Comment: @Szega I've thought about that, the trigger to end Imprisonment is "Whenever I say so or my host body dies"

Comment: @PierreCathé That seems like a very expensive and overcomplicated way to cast _Clone_

Comment: @Cubic True, but Clone has its problems too (e.g. very costly gold-wise, takes up space, takes 120 days to mature).

Comment: this is the best question headline I've ever seen for pretending that it was sent to an advice column instead

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes it is.

Your body is in a catatonic state, but isn't dead according to the Magic Jar spell. Note the wording:

> The only action you can take is to project your soul up to 100 feet out of the container, either returning to your **living** body (and ending the spell) or attempting to possess a humanoid's body.

This implies that your body is still alive after casting Magic Jar. While it's alive, it counts as a creature and is therefore a valid target for the Imprisonment spell.

Note that the rules do not give a precise definition of *creature*, but it would be very strange if a living body were not a creature. Among other things, it would be immune to [poison](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/poison-basic-vial).